# Adding items to other applications taskbar menu in Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7, taskbar

Is it possible to add other menu items to other pinned applications right click menu in the Windows 7 taskbar? I'm using .NET, but I will accept P/Invokes as well. I've been reading the documentation on the API, and can't seem to find a way to do this. I just thought I'd check here as a last ditch effort to find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The key is the application ID. If you do it through the native API you have to specify the AppID in your calls and you can just go ahead and specify the other app's AppID. If you're using Code Pack, you could set your AppID to the same as the other app, add your destinations and tasks, and perhaps set your AppID back to something else when you're done.

Comment: That sounds good, how would you get other applications "ApplicationID"?

Comment: Do you own the code in the other app? If so and you have a reason other than "I can't change the code" for wanting a second app to change the jumplist, take a look at GetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID  and SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID which get or set the app id for the current process. Note that you can't get the default one the system gave you with this function, you have to set it. You might also find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459%28VS.85%29.aspx helpful.

Comment: No I don't, I'm writing a utility application that would hopefully add tasks to other applications jump list to allow them to add new actions associated with their application. I wanted to be able to add user tasks to any application pinned to the taskbar.

Comment: From what I'm seeing it's a no?

Comment: @Dylan, perhap contact this developer http://jumplist.gsdn-media.com/site/Website:Features and ask him how he does it? I'd be interested in the answer.